# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget even though I don't use any image

Tags: android, dictionary, controller, android-mapview

I'm having a problem in my app that I never met before.I've been having this app for a while and runned it thousands of time, but I never got this error.

I have a server that receives some GPS data that are written also in a DB and a singleton class.
In one of my classes I use an Async Task thread in order to read from the singleton class the new GPS data that arrived and display those points on the map.

And now suddenly I get error at a line like this:

```
mc.animateTo(p1);

where mc=mapView.getController();
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();

    mc.setZoom(17);

    mapView.setSatellite(true);

    mapView.setStreetView(true);

    mapView.invalidate();
}


public class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void, GeoPoint, Void> {

    GeoPoint p;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {

            while (true) {


                if(number.equals("Car1"))
                {
                longitude = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastLongitude1();
                latitude = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastLatitude1();
                speed = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastSpeed1();
                loc1 = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastLocation1();
                speed = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastSpeed1();
                }



                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        speed_1.setText(Integer.toString(speed));
                        location.setText(loc1);

                    }
                });


                p = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);

                publishProgress(p);

                Thread.sleep(1500);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(GeoPoint... progress1) {

        theRouteDraw(progress1[0]);
    }
```

This is how theRouteDraw() looks like:

```
public void theRouteDraw(GeoPoint p1) {

    mc.animateTo(p1);

    mc.setZoom(17);

    mapView.setSatellite(true);

    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

ServerManager is my singleton class...I read new data from there and use publishProgress();  and the method theRouteDraw() to display those points on the map.

I'm not using any overlay or special image on my map.

I get error in this method

```
public void theRouteDraw(GeoPoint p1) {

    public void theRouteDraw(GeoPoint p1) {

    mc.animateTo(p1);

    mc.setZoom(17);

    mapView.setSatellite(true);

    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

at this line:   mc.animateTo(p1);

This is my logcat:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.generateNewTileImage(StreetViewRenderer.java
at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.renderTile(StreetViewRenderer.java:88)
at com.google.android.maps.AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.renderTile(AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.) 
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.preLoad(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.maps.MapController.animateTo(MapController.java:234)
at com.google.android.maps.MapController.animateTo(MapController.java:203)
at com.Server_1.Server4.theRouteDraw(Server4.java:159)
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maps image tiles are bitmaps and google maps does cache some images as well, so there are bitmaps being allocated. I'm facing similar problems.

In this case removing:

```
mc.animateTo(p1);
```

Will probably solve it, this seems to be throwing the error and it makes sense that this might involve the loading of quite a few images. You might have a memory leak somewhere, probably a reference to your mapview, which is the root of the problem.